# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server error while try to access SQL Server on Docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I'm beginning to work with Docker and I'm getting the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server when I try to access an SQL Server instance running on docker from an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API running in other docker instance

This is my connection string in the API's `appsettings.json`:

```
"Server=db,22;Database=OrdersDatabase;User=sa;Password=123Mudar#"
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
        env_file:
            - mssql.env
        ports:
            - "22:1433"
```

This is my `mssql.env` file:

```
SA_PASSWORD:123Mudar#
ACCEPT_EULA:Y
```

And I'm running this commands (in a .bat file):

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

What I'm missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Danilo, just a small suggestion about ports, 22 isn't a good choice, since it is reserved for `SSH`. if your host already consumed the port `1433` you could increase it or keep the original port number's format, in some way. ie: `1434`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your .env file should be in this format:

```
SA_PASSWORD=123Mudar#
ACCEPT_EULA=Y
```

use `=` instead of `:`

Also, you used port 22 for your sql server as outside port, but when using inside the container, you should use the `db` container port which is 1433

Comment: Hi Peyman, seems that it worked, but apparently the database is not being created automatically, Im getting this error: Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'OrdersDatabase'. [CLIENT: 172.18.0.3]. It is possible to apply the migrations and create the database automatically in this context?

Comment: I already have this code on the Configure method on Startup class: ordersDbContext.Database.Migrate();

Comment: the problem could be, you created the SQL server container before asking it to build the required database, or asked to build database A and you want database B. In order to start things clean from scratch, you can remove the database volume, container (created by sql server and start over). use this command: `docker-compose down --volumes` and then again `docker-compose up` it to see if it works

Comment: Hi Peyman, after a restart my computer the migration was applied, I just see your response now, but your solution makes sense and could be worked too, thank you.